# The requested default allocation is not currently assigned to this server. Pterodactyl panel

Tags: node.js, api, admin, panel

I have my own API and want to fix server edit also update the build configuration, but as I want to test it it says sth like allocation field needed, then I did go to https://dashflo.net/docs/api/pterodactyl/v1/#req_11fc764c3ed648ca8e6d60bff860ca6d to read further and in their example they used "allocation: 1", also I did that and then it says "The requested default allocation is not currently assigned to this server.", "status: 400", "code: 'DisplayException'" and I don't know how to fix it I tryied allocation: "2" or "0" but then it says invalid...

This is my Request:

```js
{
"id": id,
"allocation": "1",
'memory': RAM,
'swap': "0",
'disk': Disk,
'io': IO,
'cpu': CPU,
"threads": null,
'feature_limits': {
    'databases': AmountOfDatabases,
    'allocations': AmountOfAllocations,
    "backups": Backups
},
}
```

I am using axios to send the PATCH request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the error I need to change my create server request from

```js
{
        'name': NameOfServer,
        'user': OwnerID,
        'description': 'A Nodeactyl server',
        'egg': EggID,
        'pack': NestID,
        'docker_image': DockerImage,
        'startup': StartupCmd,
        'limits': {
            'memory': RAM,
            'swap': Swap,
            'disk': Disk,
            'io': IO,
            'cpu': CPU,
        },
        'feature_limits': {
            'databases': AmountOfDatabases,
            'allocations': AmountOfAllocations,
            'backups': backups
        },
        'environment': {
            'DL_VERSION': Version,
            'SERVER_JARFILE': 'server.jar',
            'VANILLA_VERSION': Version,
            'BUNGEE_VERSION': Version,
            'PAPER_VERSION': Version,
            'MC_VERSION': Version,
            'BUILD_NUMBER': Version,
            'INSTALL_REPO': Version,
            "BOT_JS_FILE": "index.js",
            "AUTO_UPDATE": true,
            "USER_UPLOAD": true
        },
        'allocation': {
            'default': 1,
            'additional': [],
        },
        'deploy': {
            'locations': [1],
            'dedicated_ip': false,
            'port_range': [],
        },
        'start_on_completion': true,
        'skip_scripts': false,
        'oom_disabled': true
}
```

to:

```js
{
        'name': NameOfServer,
        'user': OwnerID,
        'description': 'A Nodeactyl-v1-support server',
        'egg': EggID,
        'pack': NestID,
        'docker_image': DockerImage,
        'startup': StartupCmd,
        'limits': {
            'memory': RAM,
            'swap': Swap,
            'disk': Disk,
            'io': IO,
            'cpu': CPU,
        },
        'feature_limits': {
            'databases': AmountOfDatabases,
            'allocations': AmountOfAllocations,
            'backups': backups
        },
        'environment': {
            'DL_VERSION': Version,
            'SERVER_JARFILE': 'server.jar',
            'VANILLA_VERSION': Version,
            'BUNGEE_VERSION': Version,
            'PAPER_VERSION': Version,
            'MC_VERSION': Version,
            'BUILD_NUMBER': Version,
            'INSTALL_REPO': Version,
            "BOT_JS_FILE": "index.js",
            "AUTO_UPDATE": true,
            "USER_UPLOAD": true
        },
        "allocation": {
            "default": 1
        },
        'start_on_completion': true,
        'skip_scripts': false,
        'oom_disabled': true
}
```